# testdisk says partition table structure is bad

Tags: data-recovery

I have a dual boot system, win7 and Ubuntu 12.04, A disk crash trashed my partition table.

Here is what fdisk says about the disk:

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16291629

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1            2048    26626047    13312000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE

/dev/sda2   *    26626048    26830847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda3        26830848   543512242   258340697+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda4       543512574   976771071   216629249    5  Extended

/dev/sda5       959127552   976771071     8821760   82  Linux swap / Solaris

testdisk finds the partition, however if I make the Linux partition Logical, testdisk says the table structure is bad. Any suggestions? I have attached a screenshot of the testdisk screen:

[image]

oops, it appears that I flagged the wrong NTFS partition as bootable in testdisk.

Comment: Three primary and one extended or four primary partitions are allowed in MS-DOS partitioning layout. Maybe you tried an uncontiguous extended partition schema.